# Issues recieving and parasing a put request in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, rest, put

Having some issues parsing and retrieving a put request from a raspberry pi I have sending my website data.

I am trying to update some fields in my Worker model the controller is below

```
class WorkersController < ApplicationController

def new
   @worker = Worker.new
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def create
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @worker= Worker.new(params[:worker])
   @worker.user_id= @user.id
   if @worker.save
    flash[:success] = "Worker information saved!"
    redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'new'
   end
end


def show
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
    @MHS = params[:SUMMARY][:MHS_av]
    @worker.hashrate = @MHS
    @worker.save
end


end
```

Below is the server side incoming put request

```
Started PUT "/users/1/workers/1" for xxx.xxx.xx.xxx at 2013-06-13 03:06:02 +0000
Processing by WorkersController#update as XML
```

Now here are the parameters

```
Parameters: {"STATUS"=>[{"STATUS"=>"S", "When"=>1371092750, "Code"=>11, "Msg"=>"Summary", "Description"=>"cgminer 3.1.1"}], "SUMMARY"=>[{"Elapsed"=>60394, "MHS av"=>1.92, "Found Blocks"=>1, "Getworks"=>1217, "Accepted"=>9104, "Rejected"=>138, "Hardware Errors"=>0, "Utility"=>9.04, "Discarded"=>2428, "Stale"=>20, "Get Failures"=>1, "Local Work"=>9513, "Remote Failures"=>0, "Network Blocks"=>458, "Total MH"=>116212.6295, "Work Utility"=>1769.84, "Difficulty Accepted"=>1747840.0, "Difficulty Rejected"=>26496.0, "Difficulty Stale"=>3840.0, "Best Share"=>74960510}], "id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "worker"=>{}}
```

Followed by these Errors

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

at=info method=PUT path=/users/1/workers/1 host=miningmonitor.herokuapp.com fwd="xxx.xxx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1029ms status=500 bytes=643

TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):


app/controllers/workers_controller.rb:27:in `[]'

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 345ms



app/controllers/workers_controller.rb:27:in `update'
```

I See that Ruby on rails is thinking the incoming message is XML but its JSON do I need to specify somewhere that this put request is JSON? Also I was told Ruby on rails just parses JSON into the params and I can just pull the data from the params is that true?

adding content from application.html.erb from layouts

```
<head>
 <title>Mining Monitoring Website</title>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"%>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
```

Comment: can you show the content in the head tags in the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at it closely - SUMMARY is an array, not hash. I don't know how you're building POST (PUT) data, but accessing them in following way following should work

`params[:SUMMARY][0][:MHS_av]`

Also - please take a look at `MHS_av` - it looks like in incomming parameters it does not have an underscore.

CSRF is mising by a reason, right?

Comment: what is CSRF? also you are correct the tag is MHS av would I then use

params[:SUMMARY][0][MHS av]?

thanks

Comment: Regarding parameter - please don't use white characters - use underscores instead. If you absolutelly must to, access it like `params[:SUMMARY][0]["MHS av"]` (notice double quotes)

Comment: only if you will use underscores.